# AS3 Override const

Tags: actionscript-3, overriding, constants

I am trying to do the following:

```
public class character extends entity {
public const type:int = CHARACTER;
}


public class entity extends Sprite {
public const type:int = INVALID;

public const INVALID:int = -1;
public const CHARACTER:int = 1;
}
```

But the compiler throws:

Error: A conflict exists with inherited definition dieEngine:entity.type in namespace public. public const type:int = CHARACTER;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, constants are constants no matter if they are inherited or not and should not be overriden, think of that like the a complete class which defines two times the required constant.

If you really want to override it, you should set that `var`instead of `const`

Use:

```
public var type:int = INVALID;
```

instead of:

```
public const type:int = INVALID;
```

Comment: Well, a constant should be able to be overwritten at compile time :/

Comment: jpabluz: Thats untrue, you're thinking of FINAL constants. Regular constants should be overridable. Final is the keyword which denotes that it can no longer be overridden by superclasses/descendants

Answer (score 0):

Does this help at all? You can make the property of a MovieClip a constant that you can change:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;

    public class Controller extends MovieClip
    {
        public const IS_VALID:Boolean = true;
        public var type:MovieClip = new MovieClip;

        public function Controller()
        {
            extendedController();
        }

        protected function extendedController():void
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Then in your extended class

```
package
{
    public class ControllerExtended extends Controller
    {

        public function ControllerExtended()
        {           

        }

        override protected function extendedController():void
        {
            type.IS_VALID = false;

            trace(type.IS_VALID);

            type.IS_VALID = true;

            trace(type.IS_VALID);
        }
    }
}
```

You can make the constant an integer if you wish